# Strange Error when deploying flask app to heroku

Tags: python, github, flask, heroku

I am getting the following error in my heroku logs after recently pushing a change to my website.

`2023-08-18T20:07:37.479124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command` gunicorn main:app`2023-08-18T20:07:38.117360+00:00 app[web.1]: One or more of these arguments were missing: uid, gid, gateway, somaxconn, event_fd, out_fd`
I didn't change any server side code I just altered some text in one of my HTML files.

Now when I go to my website I get the following logged errors:

`2023-08-18T20:12:14.650751+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=<MY_CLIENTS_WEBSITE_NAME_HIDDEN_FOR_PRIVACY> request_id=c104e18c-8b75-44a8-8f7d-3d36eaaa0399 fwd="86.174.72.241" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

I can't find any resources for this error online and heroku support just redirects you to external resources. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried to reverse my commits back to their original state and this did nothing to remedy the problem. I have tried altering my Procfile.